# Android ndk error asm types.h not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

After updating Android Studio to 2.3.3 and updating ndk bundles，my project fails to build. What does the error mean? It should be a bug of the IDE. How to fix the issue or how to go back to prior Android Studio/ndk versions?

```
Error:注: 某些输入文件使用或覆盖了已过时的 API。
注: 有关详细信息, 请使用 -Xlint:deprecation 重新编译。
注: /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/java/com/greatcompanyx/ExcellentApk/yjzb/CtrlNetTool.java使用了未经检查或不安全的操作。
注: 有关详细信息, 请使用 -Xlint:unchecked 重新编译。
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildRelease'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /home/noob/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a --target greatcompany-foot}
  [1/1] Re-running CMake...
  -- Configuring done
  使用Android编译设置
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a
  [1/17] Building CXX object src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/Buffer.cpp.o
  [2/17] Building CXX object src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/aec/aec.cpp.o
  [3/17] Building CXX object src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/beamforming/delaysum.cpp.o
  [4/17] Building CXX object src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_kws.cpp.o
  [5/17] Building CXX object src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_posthandler.cpp.o
  [6/17] Building CXX object src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_feature_extractor.cpp.o
  FAILED: /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -Dgreatcompany_foot_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/3rdparty/eigen3 -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/utils -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/beamforming -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -O3 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a -Wno-parentheses -Os -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_posthandler.cpp.o -MF src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_posthandler.cpp.o.d -o src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_posthandler.cpp.o -c /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_posthandler.cpp
  In file included from /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_posthandler.cpp:5:
  In file included from ../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/utils/json/json.h:50:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:36:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/malloc.h:22:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:42:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/sys/types.h:36:
  /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/linux/types.h:21:10: fatal error: 'asm/types.h' file not found
  #include <asm/types.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  FAILED: /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -Dgreatcompany_foot_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/3rdparty/eigen3 -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/utils -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/beamforming -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -O3 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a -Wno-parentheses -Os -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_feature_extractor.cpp.o -MF src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_feature_extractor.cpp.o.d -o src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_feature_extractor.cpp.o -c /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_feature_extractor.cpp
  In file included from /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_feature_extractor.cpp:5:
  In file included from /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_feature_extractor.h:18:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:36:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/malloc.h:22:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:42:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/sys/types.h:36:
  /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/linux/types.h:21:10: fatal error: 'asm/types.h' file not found
  #include <asm/types.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  FAILED: /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -Dgreatcompany_foot_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/3rdparty/eigen3 -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/utils -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/beamforming -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -O3 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a -Wno-parentheses -Os -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/aec/aec.cpp.o -MF src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/aec/aec.cpp.o.d -o src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/aec/aec.cpp.o -c /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/aec/aec.cpp
  In file included from /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/aec/aec.cpp:5:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/iostream:39:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/ostream:38:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/ios:38:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/iosfwd:40:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/postypes.h:40:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/cwchar:44:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/wchar.h:32:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:42:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/sys/types.h:36:
  /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/linux/types.h:21:10: fatal error: 'asm/types.h' file not found
  #include <asm/types.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  FAILED: /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -Dgreatcompany_foot_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/3rdparty/eigen3 -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/utils -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/beamforming -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -O3 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a -Wno-parentheses -Os -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_kws.cpp.o -MF src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_kws.cpp.o.d -o src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_kws.cpp.o -c /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_kws.cpp
  In file included from /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/kws/sentence/Sentence_kws.cpp:6:
  In file included from ../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/utils/json/json.h:50:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:36:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/malloc.h:22:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:42:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/sys/types.h:36:
  /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/linux/types.h:21:10: fatal error: 'asm/types.h' file not found
  #include <asm/types.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  FAILED: /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -Dgreatcompany_foot_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/3rdparty/eigen3 -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/utils -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/beamforming -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -O3 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a -Wno-parentheses -Os -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/Buffer.cpp.o -MF src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/Buffer.cpp.o.d -o src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/Buffer.cpp.o -c /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/Buffer.cpp
  In file included from /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/Buffer.cpp:5:
  In file included from ../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/Buffer.h:11:
  In file included from ../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/3rdparty/eigen3/Eigen/Core:80:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/complex:45:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/sstream:38:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/istream:38:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/ios:38:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/iosfwd:40:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/postypes.h:40:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/cwchar:44:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/wchar.h:32:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:42:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/sys/types.h:36:
  /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/linux/types.h:21:10: fatal error: 'asm/types.h' file not found
  #include <asm/types.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  FAILED: /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -Dgreatcompany_foot_EXPORTS -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/3rdparty/eigen3 -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/utils -I../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/beamforming -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -O3 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a -Wno-parentheses -Os -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/beamforming/delaysum.cpp.o -MF src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/beamforming/delaysum.cpp.o.d -o src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/CMakeFiles/greatcompany-foot.dir/src/modules/beamforming/delaysum.cpp.o -c /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/beamforming/delaysum.cpp
  In file included from /home/noob/code/greatcompany/ExcellentApk/app/src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/beamforming/delaysum.cpp:4:
  In file included from ../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/modules/beamforming/delaysum.h:14:
  In file included from ../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/3rdparty/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1:
  In file included from ../../../../src/main/cpp/greatcompany-foot/src/3rdparty/eigen3/Eigen/Core:80:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/complex:45:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/sstream:38:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/istream:38:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/ios:38:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/iosfwd:40:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/postypes.h:40:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/cwchar:44:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/wchar.h:32:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:42:
  In file included from /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/sys/types.h:36:
  /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/linux/types.h:21:10: fatal error: 'asm/types.h' file not found
  #include <asm/types.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Android studio 3.0 and ndk 15, I got this error too.
But I resolved this, but analyse it in chinese.

http://www.jianshu.com/p/27f98165d73d

## Method :

```
if(${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi)
elseif(${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "arm64-v8a")
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android)
else()
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi)
endif()
```

## Method 2

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-isystem /home/cc/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi")

## Method 3

include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi)

Comment: what about Android.mk?

Comment: Sorry, didn't cover that. May some other can answer it.

Answer (score 12):

Method one from Lemac's answer works for me with the slight modifications:

```
if (${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "x86_64")
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android)
elseif (${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "x86")
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/i686-linux-android)
elseif (${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "arm64-v8a")
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android)
elseif (${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi)
endif()
```

Android Studio version 3.0.1 with NDK 16.1.4479499.

Comment: Great answer by a great programmer! :D

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to Alex Cohn answer, in my case a problem was presence of 
`set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS,...)` in my CMakeList.txt
This declaration overlaps CMAKE_C_FLAGS set in .gradle `externalNativeBuild{ cmake { cFlags="..."}}`

It seems that -isystem is added by Gradle plugin to CFLAGS not to include dirs list

Comment: I think Android Studio's gradle settings about CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS are not the root cause. It is **android.toolchain.cmake** this file overwrite some stuffs to CMAKE_C_FLAGS and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

Answer (score 2):

Your compile parameters miss

```
-isystem /home/noob/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
```

You have upgraded NDK to r15, but not the Android Studio and gradle plugin. For me, Android Studio 3.0 (preview) with `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'` (which is not the latest), generates the correct compilation commands.

You can add the path to `…/include/arm-linux-androideabi` manually if you don't want to switch to preview version of Android Studio.

Comment: So it's really the IDE's bug or I misconfigure anything? I installed Android Studio 3.0 and set gradle version as 2.3.1, but it still fails to build. Adding `include_directories(...path/to/arm-linux-androideabi)` to CMakeLists.txt eliminates this error, but raises a new error `undefined reference to stderr`. Everything just works fine before I upgrade the NDK, I don't understand what changes the upgrade operation takes in.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. After all, I solved this problem by downgrading NDK to r14b. I download the *android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64.zip*, unzip and replace everything in `Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle`. Now it works again. But I still do not know how to work with NDK r15.

Comment: I don't know. If you can afford further investigation, you can switch back to r15 and remove the `.externalNativeBuild` directory, to force CMake to run from scratch. My result is: app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi/android_gradle_build.json contains `-isystem …/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi` for **"flags"**.

Comment: Clearing the cmake cache is probably all that's needed. Any CMake fixes that were needed for r15 were also included in r15, so everything should be self-consistent.

Comment: Clearing the cmake cache doesn't work on Windows. I haven't tested it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've met a very similar case. I set `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` in CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${MY_CUSTOM_C_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${MY_CUSTOM_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

However, since android.toolchain.cmake is used as toolchain file when calling cmake, cmake will first interpret android.toolchain.cmake's content (which will setting values on CMAKE_C_FLAGS and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS), then loading my settings in CMakeLists.txt. That is to say, I finally changed to this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${MY_CUSTOM_C_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${MY_CUSTOM_CXX_FLAGS}")
```