# Updating application with C++ native library to NDK 18, cmake isn't including required sysroot platform include directory

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I have an Android application, developed with Android Studio, that is using a very old build system - NDK 14 with CMake 3.6 and AGP 3.5. I'm trying to update it to NDK 18 (I eventually want to update it to latest NDK, but baby steps) using CMake 3.18.1 and AGP 4.2.2 with Gradle 6.7.1, but the build fails due to errors finding a system include file `asm/types.h`.

Looking at the clang++ compile command that CMake generates, it is clearly missing the `${SYSROOT}/usr/include/<platform-abi>` directory.

My CMake (which worked well for NDK 14 with CMake 3.6.1) has these lines:

```
if(${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI} STREQUAL arm64-v8a)
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android)
elseif(${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI} STREQUAL x86_64)
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android)
endif()
```

Running CMake with `--trace-expand`, I can see it correctly parses those lines:

```
…
… arm64Release|arm64-v8a :/home/…/myapp/mynativelib/CMakeLists.txt(5):
  if(arm64-v8a STREQUAL arm64-v8a )
… arm64Release|arm64-v8a :/home/…/myapp/mynativelib/CMakeLists.txt(6):  
include_directories(/home/…/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android )
…
```

But the `build.ninja` file generated does not have this include directory - it contains compile directives that look like so:

```
build CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/home/…/mynativelib/MyClass.cpp.o: \
    CXX_COMPILER__mynativelib_Debug /home/…/mynativelib/MyClass.cpp || \
    cmake_object_order_depends_target_mynativelib
  DEFINES = -DANDROID -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DDEBUG -DMIXIT=0 -DNDEBUG -DRELEASE=0 … -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
  DEP_FILE = CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/home/…/mynativelib/MyClass.cpp.o.d
  FLAGS = -std=c++14 -fno-stack-protector -ffor-scope -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info \
    -fPIC -fno-stack-protector -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes \
    -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fomit-frame-pointer -UNDEBUG -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Ijni -Wformat \
    -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-stack-protector -std=c++14
  INCLUDES = -I/home/…/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/include \
    -I../../../../../../../some-custom-include-from-cmake \
    -isystem /home/…/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include
    -isystem /home/…/Android/Sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir
  OBJECT_FILE_DIR = CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/home/…/mynativelib
```

I can see that the build command include the `some-custom-include-from-cmake` include directory, that is added in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, as well as all the `cxx-stl/llvm-libc++` includes that are also added in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, but the `/usr/include/<android-abi>` platform include dir is missing.

Even if I use the `include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android)` command without the `if` check, right near where the other `include_directories()` commands that do make it into the build file, it is still missing from the build file. I even tried to add the `-I` flag directly using `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)` and that didn't cause the required include dir to be listed.

OTOH, if I change the `include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}…)` to be something that doesn't start with `${ANDROID_SYSROOT}`, or points to a non-existing directory - then whatever I put there does make it to the `build.ninja` file.

Looks like something is very purposefully removing include directories that are in `${ANDROID_SYSROOT}` maybe?

Comment: BTW - AGP, since version 4, annoyingly does not allow the `arguments` configuration to have just any CMake supported args, but only defines. see this ticket for more details: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159434435 , so getting it to run CMake with `--trace` was a practice in frustration.

Comment: I thought the correct sysroot was set for you automatically so that you don't have to do it yourself(?) (i.e. ndk/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake). Though I don't have r18 installed so I haven't checked that version specifically.

Comment: @Michael I inherited this project, but I suspect the sysroot system includes were added to address this issue of `'asm/types.h' file not found` originally: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44793617/53538